# is there any inbuilt function in sql to implement following operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have `table` like this

```
column1 column2 column3
1   12  1
1   12  2
1   4   3
1   5   4
1   34  5
2   36  6
2   22  7
2   12  8
2   2   9
2   4   10
2   41  11
3   44  12
3   55  13
3   66  14
3   34  15
```

I need to add **extra** `column`.after that table should be like this

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
1   12  1   1
1   12  2   2
1   4   3   3
1   5   4   4
1   34  5   5
2   36  6   1
2   22  7   2
2   12  8   3
2   2   9   4
2   4   10  5
2   41  11  6
3   44  12  1
3   55  13  2
3   66  14  3
3   34  15  4
```

according to `column1` values `column4` values should be add.
please help to get solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you clarify your problem? Also: What have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a set of built in [**ranking functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).

Here is one of them, the [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column1) Column5
FROM table;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fd22/1)